# How to add a subdomain and avoid to create a new folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, subdomain

On my shared hosting, I have just created a new subdomain **static.example.com** but it has also create a new folder **www.example.com/static/** .

How can I avoid to create these new folders every time I create a new subdomain ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason why this folder is created is simple. The hosting company just adds a entry into your DNS zone file, something like:

> static            A                 W.X.Y.Z

where W.X.Y.Z is the IP of your existing site 'example.com'. Then they'd creates a virtual host in apache config - `static.example.com` and sets its DocumentRoot to  `<server_path>/public_html/static`.

I am sure your problem is not with the folder itself (how else will you organize all the files for static sub-domain if not in a subfolder) but with the fact the files are also accessible via the URL `www.example.com/static`

One solution is that you can ask your hosting company to put the `static` folder outside your current document root so that it is not addressable as a subfolder of current DocumentRoot.

What I mean to say is that your current directory structure could look like:

> \ 
>   - public_html 
>      -  static

where public_html is your DocumentRoot for example.com (couldbe called `httpdocs` or some other name based on your hosting env)

You need to ask them to move static folder only level up to something like:

> \ 
>   - public_html 
>   -  static

static is now a sibling of old DocumentRoot and not a child of it. It will be no longer addressable via `www.example.com/static` now. /static is a new DocumenRoot for your new subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

On a shared hosting site the hosts software normally does this. I think this is an unintended behavior and you should contact your host provider. It is not normal that a subdomain can be accessed via appending a path to the main domain.